# pipe as delimiter in regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, fluentd

```
2020-09-16 04:47:49 | info | PHP | BACKEND | 01ARZ3NDEKTSV4RRFFQ69G5FAV | Login not successfully. Please try again
```

Above is my sample logging format which will be sent to fluentd, and I did regular expression as follow:

```
<parse>
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  expression /^(?<timestamp>(.*?\|))(?<level>(.*?\|))(?<language>(.*?\|))(?<service>(.*?\|))(?<uuid>(.*?\|))(?<message>.*)/
  @type regexp
</parse>
```

Problem is when I render that one, pipe `|` is included in string. Please let me know how to ignore or skip `|` there? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `|` outside of your group: `^(?<timestamp>(.*?))\|(?<level>(.*?))\|(?<language>(.*?))\|(?<service>(.*?))\|(?<uuid>(.*?))\|(?<message>.*)`

See: https://regex101.com/r/8rFRPa/2

Comment: Can you help me to trim space each of matching string as well?

Comment: That would be `^(?<timestamp>(.*?))\|(?<level>(.*?))\|(?<language>(.*?))\|(?<service>(.*?))\|(?<uuid>(.*?))\|(?<message>.*)`, see: https://regex101.com/r/8rFRPa/4